# JSF Primefaces - Command button not redirecting

Tags: jsf, redirect, button, primefaces, commandbutton

I have tried this command buttons and many more:

```
<p:commandButton value="Redirect" action="/tiposDocumentos.xhtml"/>

<p:commandButton value="Redirect" action="/administrador/tiposDocumentos.xhtml"/>

<p:commandButton value="Redirect" action="administrador/tiposDocumentos.xhtml"/>
```

I'm literarlly going nuts with this. I have other command buttons working like a charm, but this one is making me crazy!

This is my folder structure:
[image]

When someone logs in as an administrator, is redirected to the file "initialMenu.xhtml" with this command button (which works)

```
<p:commandButton value="Sign - in" action="#{loginView.login}" update="msgGrowl" />
```

Then I don't know how to redirect to "TiposDocumentos.xhtml". Please, help.

I'm using SpringSecurity and other buttons that don't use the "login" method also work.

I can also redirect to "tiposDocumentos.xhtml" from login if I put it outside the "administrador" folder.

Comment: You forgot the most important part of the question: what exactly happens instead?

Comment: I click the button and nothing happens

Comment: Uh right. Please elaborate the problem in webdeveloper's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. This site is to support website developers, not website endusers. Start with pressing F12 in your webbrowser and inspecting JS console and Network monitor for clues.

Comment: Hmm... This is my first web project so I'm not too familiar with how html elements interface with primefaces. Anyways, I just found out this is caused by Spring Security.

Comment: I´m just going to leave this here in case anyone looks for this question: This is a very common problem with Spring Security. After a successful login it gets a little complicated to redirect. Search: Spring Security redirect after login.

Comment: This question is useless without an answer or link to the answer you found.

Comment: Many links: https://www.google.com.co/?ion=1&espv=2#q=Spring+Security+redirect+after+login  First link: http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login I didn't solve it because it isn't necessary for me. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `"faces-redirect=true"`"as explained [here](https://kamwo.me/java-jsf-redirection-with-commandbutton/) and elsewhere

```
<p:commandButton id="btn_cr" 
        value="Redirect"
        ajax="false"
        action="/tiposDocumentos.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Please do not post "try this" answers as long as you haven't reproduced the described problem and tested the proposed solution on your own. If you're not able to do this, post a comment instead.

Comment: @BaluC - point noted ! Thanks for pointing the correct way !!

Comment: @TheCoder You missed the `ajax="false"` from the mentioned link. Quote: By setting ajax to false we suppress the default use of AJAX and a asynchornous call to the backend.